# 'Could not find or load main class' when I write the package, Visual Code

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, package

I'm trying to run Java code in vscode, but I have some troubles.

When I try to run it with terminal and I don't write the package line, the code works well, but when I write it, it doens't work anymore.

This is what I mean,

[image: successful screenshot]

I didn't write the package line and it worked, but then I wrote it, and I don't know what happened,

[image: error screenshot]

I'm really new with VisualCode and Java in general, so, I don't know if it because I don't know something about it, but well, I'll try to study it, but first I need to figure out what it's going on. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

The class name is not `test`. It's `myjava.src.pkg.test`.

So you should go to the root directory (workspace) and execute `java myjava.src.pkg.test`.

Or stay i this directory and execute `java -cp ../../.. myjava.src.pkg.test`.

Note that classes normally start with an uppercase letter.

I strongly advise to never quit the root directory (workspace), and to execute all your commands from there. I also strongly advise putting your sources ina dedicated directory, and compiling your classes to a separate one.

Comment: Thank you very much! this actually worked, but now, how can I compile the file without being in the file directory ../workspace/myjava/src/pkg and then 'javac test.java'

Comment: I mean, that is for compile there, but if I am in the root directory I don't find a way to compile it (javac myjava.src.pkg.test.java didn't work)

Comment: javac myjava/src/pkg/test.java

Comment: Thank you man, I do really appreciate it, I think with this I can start, and then learn many things that I don't know yet.